# Sending Pictures over Network with Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg

I am currently working with the HoloLens and thus Unity. The idea is to make a webcam Livestream with as little delay as possible to an instance of FFmpeg on a different device for encoding. However, I run into some issues.

My first problem is the Conversion from a Color32 Array to a Byte Array. It creates a huge amount of bandwidth, especially when I am trying to record and stream with 30fps and a 1280x720 resolution.
Here is some code:

```
IEnumerator Init()
    {
        webCam = new WebCamTexture(1280, 720, 30);
        webCam.Play();
        image.texture = webCam;
        Debug.Log("WebCam Width: " + webCam.width);
        Debug.Log("WebCam Height: " + webCam.height);
        currentTexture = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);
        
        data = new Color32[webCam.width * webCam.height];
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10305);
        listener.Start();



        while (webCam.width < 100)
        {
            
             yield return null;
        }

        StartCoroutine("Recording");
    }

    WaitForEndOfFrame endOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    IEnumerator Recording()
    {

        TcpClient tcpClient = null;
        NetworkStream tcpStream = null;
        bool isConnected = false;

        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            while(!stopCapture)
            {
                tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Debug.Log("Client Connected!");
                isConnected = true;
                tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            }
        });
        while(!isConnected)
        {
            yield return endOfFrame;
        }
        readyToGetFrame = true;
        byte[] messageLength = new byte[SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT];
        while(!stopCapture)
        {
            yield return endOfFrame;

            webCam.GetPixels32(data);
            byte[] webCamBytes = Utilities.Color32ArrayToByteArray(data);
                                
            readyToGetFrame = false;
            Loom.RunAsync(() => {
                tcpStream.Write(webCamBytes, 0, webCamBytes.Length);
                readyToGetFrame = true;
            });

            while (!readyToGetFrame)
            {
                yield return endOfFrame;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static byte[] Color32ArrayToByteArray(Color32[] colors)
    {
        if (colors == null || colors.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int lengthOfColor32 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Color32));
        int byteArrayLength = lengthOfColor32 * colors.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteArrayLength];

        GCHandle handle = default(GCHandle);

        try
        {
            handle = GCHandle.Alloc(colors, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, byteArrayLength);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(handle != default(GCHandle))
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

To fix this problem, I tried to use EncodePNG and EncodeJPG instead. But there is my second problem. If I use these methods, I got a big loss of performance.

So instead of this

```
        webCam.GetPixels32(data);
        byte[] webCamBytes = Utilities.Color32ArrayToByteArray(data);
```

I use this

```
        currentTexture.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
        byte[] webCamBytes = currentTexture.EncodeToJPG();
```

Thus my question:
**Is there any way to reduce the bandwith by maybe cutting off the alpha values as they are not needed? Or is there another good way such as converting to a different color or picture format?**

Because right now I ran out of usable ideas and feel kinda stuck. Might just be me though ;-)

PS: Using external libraries is a tad difficult as it needs to run on HoloLens and due to other regulations.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: You're basically reinventing a streaming video codec. You start with sending uncompressed bitmaps and find out that requires a lot of bandwidth. Then you use a (probably unoptimized for speed) JPEG encoder, and find out that (even if you overcome the performance issues) that still requires too much bandwidth. Then you start wondering _"what if I could only send the differences between the frames?"_ and so on. Why do you want your encoder on a different system? What original problem are you trying to solve? Why won't Video Capture (`VideoCapture.CreateAsync()`) work?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for your comment. I am new here and have to learn how to ask good questions. The reason for not running an encoder on the Hololens is: power. Battery and computing power. It's fairly limited and even if h264 encoding in real-time with minimal latency and somewhat okayish quality would work, the bandwidth afterwards is limited even further. That's why there's a second piece of hardware included, it is more powerful (and encodes the camera feed of the Hololens in VP9 due to the limited bandwidth afterwards) and directly connected to the Hololens via LAN/WLAN.

Comment: @CodeCaster Furthermore it doesn't run on batteries unlike the Hololens. 
But I see your point with reinventing codecs on a very basic level. however I am trying to reduce the bandwidth a little bit (as it seems to be the current bottleneck, I don't know how much compression it needs), not by a huge margin, without sacrificing all of the current performance. 
As far as I'm concerned VideoCapture can only save to files and not stream, thus creating a huge delay, defeating the purpose of realtime streaming with as little delay as possible.

Comment: You shouldn't use TCP for the video stream if the goal is a live view it would probably be enough to only synchronize as many frames as possible. I think using an encoding background thread and UDP might already improve performance

Comment: Encoding what is essentially doing is compressing your data in a smart way that is performant and bandwidth-efficient, and you have parameters where you can say what is the most important for you. Just go with the existing codec you can [pick and match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_codecs) to your liking, you can reduce resolution/bitrate/quality/compression and pick what would work the best.  You are currently in a triangle and you can pick 2. Performance, bandwidth, CPU cycles. Also, use UDP

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for your answer! I see the usagae of UDP. With UDP I run into the MTU Problem. An UDP Package can only has a size of 65535 bytes. If I want to send more bytes, than i have to to split my bytes into several UDP packages and reassemble them on the other, right?

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak Thanks for your answer! I will try to play arround with different settings :-)